# Why does the computation of np.fft.fft2 depends on the shape of the image?

Tags: numpy, image-processing, fft

I'm computing the **fft** in 2 dimensions on images buffers of various sizes. I noticed that for some shapes, the computation time increases abruptly.

I am using python 3.7 and numpy 1.16.0. I also tried with **pyfftw** and the problem does not appear there.

Here is a code example highlighting my problem with numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

fake_image = np.ones((1000,8192))
for i in range(200,700,50):
    crop = fake_image[:,i:]

    start = time.time()
    res_scipak = np.fft.fft2(crop)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"{i}: {end-start}")
```

I obtain the following result:

```
200: 0.8815453052520752
250: 0.8947739601135254
300: 16.496759176254272
350: 9.420636177062988
400: 4.677924156188965
450: 1.1415870189666748
500: 4.911479711532593
550: 29.64967179298401
600: 1.1793103218078613
650: 3.6275839805603027
```

I would actually expect to see the computation time decreasing when the number of columns decreases.

Answer (score 3):

fft works best on sizes that factor into small primes. With that in mind compare your observation to:

```
import sympy

for i in range(200,700,50):
    print(i,sympy.primefactors(8192-i))

200 [2, 3, 37]
250 [2, 11, 19]
300 [2, 1973]
350 [2, 3, 1307]
400 [2, 487]
450 [2, 7, 79]
500 [2, 3, 641]
550 [2, 3821]
600 [2, 13, 73]
650 [2, 3, 419]
```

Why does it not apply to pyfftw? There are ways to deal with large prime numbers, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rader%27s_FFT_algorithm, which appears to be [what fftw uses](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/master/rdft/dht-rader.c).